# Jansenism's views of marriage?

Tags: marriage, jansenism, catharism

What are Jansenism's views of marriage? Were they akin to Manicheans' and Albigensians'? Who was a prominent Jansenist who wrote about marriage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jansenists were known for adhering to errors on grace condemned by Innocent X in 1568 ([DZ 10](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n1000)92 ff.). Opposed to the Jesuits' presumed laxity, they were moral rigorists ("hards"), who, according to Noonan's [*Contraception*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6558) p. 317,

> insisted on the Augustinian tie between sexual acts, concupiscence, and original sin. They [unlike St. Augustine] insisted on the sinfulness of initiating intercourse with any purpose other than procreation.

Thus, the Jansenists appear to have an extreme procreative view of sexual intercourse. The Cathars / Alibegensians were against procreation because, like the Manicheans, they believed the material/bodily world is evil and that marriage is, too, because it "traps" souls in bodies.

Catholic teaching is that ([*Summa Theologica* suppl. q. 49 a. 5](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/XP/XP049.html#XPQ49A5THEP1) co. // [*Super Sent.*, lib. 4 d. 31 q. 2 a. 2](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/snp4027.html#19806) co.)

> when married persons come together for the purpose of begetting children, or of paying the debt to one another (which pertains to "faith[fulness]") they are wholly excused from sin.
> <sub>[quando conjuges conveniunt causa prolis procreandae, vel ut sibi invicem debitum reddant, quae ad fidem pertinent; totaliter excusantur a peccato.]</sub>

Martin de Barcos, a student of Cornelius Jansen himself, was a prominent Jansenist theologian. De Barcos promoted the heresy that "St. Peter and St. Paul are the two princes of the Church who form one head." ([DZ 10](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n1000)91). What he wrote about pleasure in marriage in [*Du decalogue* pp. 296](https://books.google.com/books?id=qXfnEXzJXH0C&pg=PA296)-301 does not appear to be contrary to Catholic teaching on marriage.

The Jansenist philosopher Pascal also seems "to have an extreme procreative view" of marriage when he writes ([Pensées diverses III – Fragment n° 65 / 85](http://www.penseesdepascal.fr/XXV/XXV65-approfondir.php)):

> les filles de Loth, par exemple, qui n’avaient que le désir des enfants, étaient plus pures sans mariage que les mariés sans désir d’enfant.
> <sub>the daughters of Lot, for example, who only desired children, were purer without marriage than marrieds who have no desire for children.</sub>

This statement depreciates virginal marriage.